# Core data SIGABIT error but error returns nothing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I got following error at fetchedResultsController performFetch method.

Unresolved error (null), (null)

```
- (void)reloadFetchedResults:(NSNotification*)notification {
    DLog(@"reloadFetchedResults");
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) { //<- Error Here
        DLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort(); 
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Does anyone have the similar experience?
Please give me a direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `_fetchedResultsController` is not nil?

Comment: Thanks! you saved my day. I didn't initialise fetchResultsController properly for debugging..